# The inheritance of Mr. Jones

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, cipher, geography, music

When I went to get the mail this morning, I noticed an official-looking letter in my mailbox. It said 'Quick 'n Quiet Notary Service' on the back, and it was addressed to me. Curious about the content I quickly opened the letter:

```
Dear Mr. ...,

We regret to inform you that Mr. Jones has passed away April 15th this year. Since you
are included in his will we kindly request you to visit our office at 20 Main Street,
San Francisco, CA to collect your belongings.

Kind Regards,

John Doe
Quick 'n Quiet Notary Service
```

Mr. Jones, my old music teacher! Although I hadn't seen him in years, it still came as a shock. We got along well, but I didn't expect him to include me in his will.

Of course I went to the notary's office to pick up the stuff Mr. Jones left me, expecting maybe one of his musical instruments or music books. However, there was only a small note with some text and some lines consisting of either numbers or letters:

> Hi ...,
>
> I know that you always liked to solve puzzles, so here I have one last puzzle for you. You have to solve it in order to know where you can find what I have left you. Good luck!
>
> Mr. Jones
>
> > 41.853589.87.624230
> >     52.561989.13.365710
> >     40.536355.79.715797
> >     39.096849.120.03235
> >     34.131270.118.49044
> >     40.848156.73.997639
> >     46.570230.3.3340090
> >
> > NZXDNJXWKUFIVFBGHFGFIJQLYZQLNWWMMBFPU

So now I'm sitting here, trying to figure out what the note and the seemingly random sequences of numbers and letters mean. Can you help me? Where should I go to find what Mr. Jones left me?

---

*Update:*

> It has been two days now since I received the strange note, and unfortunately I'm still stuck. I have been thinking about the time I took his music lessons though. He used to tell me about all of his trips around the world. Every time he told me where he was going it didn't really make sense to me, but when he told me the story behind that particular place it wasn't that strange after all...

---

*Update:*

> I still have no idea where to go, and I really want to know! I remembered another thing about Mr. Jones though. Every time he returned from one of his trips we would practice a new song, and he would tell me all kinds of funny stories about the artist. He always ended those lessons with saying 'And remember: When you go to a country, you always have to visit the capital'. Even when he hadn't gone to a capital himself! Strange man...

Comment: Is 'heritage' in the title an intentional use? Or did you mean to say 'inheritance'?

Comment: @CodeNewbie I'll edit it, it's not intentional or a clue. If you happen to find more errors or things that are not clear please let me know :)

Comment: digits maps well to earth coordinates (some require minus). I see places in Pennsylvania, Germany, France, some lake in Nevada, Los Angeles... actually too specific to be coincidence.

Comment: I agree. The one in LA looks like it's Mulholland Drive; some connection with the movie? (The other places don't have convincing-looking movie connections that I can see, though.)

Comment: also the name of the street in France is probably a hint about how the long string is encrypted

Comment: Oh, good catch!

Comment: (It's "Rue Vigenere".)

Comment: I think we're in need of a hint here.

Comment: I think we need a poke in the right direction, here, Wu33o. :)

Comment: Berlin is a capital.

Comment: [Capitol Records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitol_Records) perhaps?

Answer (score 9):

Partial discoveries:

> 41.853589,-87.624230 - 2120 S Michigan Ave, Chicago, IL 60616 (<strike>Chess Record office</strike>), there is also Blues Heaven Foundation there which is related to music tho'
>
>  52.561989,13.365710 - MarkStrasse 40, 13409 Berlin (<strike>Lidl</strike>)
>  40.536355,-79.715797 - 302 Johnson Blvd, New Kensington PA 15068
>  39.096849,-120.03235 - Lake Tahoe, NV/CA
>  34.131270,-118.49044 - Mulholland Dr,
>  40.848156,-73.997639 - 280 Broad Ave, Palisades Park, NJ 07650
>  46.570230,3.3340090 - Rue Vigenere 14, 03000 Moulins (most probably cipher Vigenere)

Comment: You're on the right track, but three of the seven names/places need some improvement before they actually make sense.

Comment: @Wu33o added full addresses as seen at exact locations :)

Comment: You have all the information you need from the coordinates, so now you need to figure out what these places have in common. It might be a good idea to take a(nother) look at the other answer...

Answer (score 5):

Ok so here is what I got so far:

> The first place, 2120 South Michigan Avenue, is both an instrumental by the Rolling Stones and an album by George Thorogood. 
> The second place, Niedergörsdorf, Germany, has had some sort of music festival there since 2011. Also, those specific coordinates ended up giving me some kind of windmill, so I don't know if that's a coincidence or some other music reference I'm missing. 
> The third place, Johnson Boulevard, was also a song, this one by Amos Lee. 
> The fourth place, Lake Tahoe, also has music festivals. 
> The fifth place, Palisades Park, was yet another song, by Freddy Cannon. 
> The last place probably means that the code at the bottom is coded with Vigenere cipher, which of course, needs a key. 
> Presumably, this could be like the literal musical key the song is in, or something linking all these festivals and songs together. I can't figure out that bit, though. 
> Also, Quick n' Quiet sounds like a clue, like rock n' roll or something, but I'm still figuring that part out...

Comment: There is also song named 40 Mark Strasse by The Shins.

Comment: And a song called "Lake Tahoe" by Kate Bush.

Answer (score 3):

Trying to move this forward, some research below, (Song, Group, Label, Lead Singer):

> 1. 2120 S Michigan Ave, Rolling Stones, Decca, Mick Jagger
>  2. 40 Mark Strasse, The Shins, Columbia Records, James Mercer
>  3. Johnson Boulevard, Amos Lee, Blue Note Records, Amos Lee
>  4. Lake Tahoe, Kate Bush, Anti-, Kate Bush
>  5. Mulholland Drive, Failure, Failure Records, Ken Andrews
>  6. Palisades Park, Freddy Cannon, Swan Records, Freddy Cannon